# cx_Freeze cannot open shared object file on linux

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I freezed py files on linux with this options form virtual env in directory /home/user/env/:

```
build_exe_options = {
                     "packages": ["generic", 
                                  "ui", 
                                  "requests", 
                                  "pickle", 
                                  "Crypto", 
                                  "base64", 
                                  "threading", 
                                  "os", 
                                  "collections",
                                  "PySide",
                                  "asyncio",
                                  "platform",
                                 "atexit",
                                 "PySide.QtNetwork",
                                 "PySide.QtWebKit"],

                     "optimize": 2,
                     "compressed": True,
                     "include_files": ["res"],
                     "include_msvcr": True,
                     }


setup(   
    name = "test",   
    version = '10',   
    description = "Test",   
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("test.py", base=None)]
)
```

When virtual env directory exists, on which build was performed all works ok, but when I rename it (for example to env1) and run "./test" I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _SpecMethods(spec)._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    return self._load_backward_compatible()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "ExtensionLoader_ui_login.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_ui_login.py", line 14, in __bootstrap__
  File "ui/login.py", line 7, in init ui.login (ui/login.c:5844)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2284, in _handle_fromlist
    _call_with_frames_removed(import_, from_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    return _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    module = _SpecMethods(spec)._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    return self._load_backward_compatible()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    spec.loader.load_module(spec.name)
  File "ExtensionLoader_PySide_QtGui.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_PySide_QtGui.py", line 14, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libpyside.cpython-34m.so.1.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The "ls libpyside.cpython-34m.so.1.2" in same directory show:
"libpyside.cpython-34m.so.1.2"

strace test show, absolute pathes, e.g.:

```
open("/home/user/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PySide/tls/i686/sse2/libpyside.cpython-34m.so.1.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

On Windows same config freezes ok.